# Change output of wordpress function inside plugin and use it in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

So... I'm developing a wordpress plugin and it is suppose to change source of images that you get from wordpress function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`

You have a theme and there you get sources for images with `get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id)` and it returns something like this `https://wordpress/path/to/image.jpg` and I want to change the output of that function INSIDE that plugin, like when I modify it in my plugin and you use that function inside your theme it outputs my modified version.

I tried using `add_filter()` and it just doesn't work and I don't know if it's even supposed to work.

```
function my_function_idk( $example ) {
    $asd = $example.'lul123';
    return $asd;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_post_thumbnail_url', 'my_function_idk' );
// expected output: https://wordpress/path/to/image.jpglul123
```

Actual output: `https://wordpress/path/to/image.jpg`

Maybe I understood that you have to use `apply_filters()` to make that filter work, but you need to use it in THAT THEME and I don't want that. I just want to modify that function... Is it possible?

I just don't understand their documentation... I'm raging over wordpress... fkn bulsht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use hook like `add_filter( 'get_the_post_thumbnail_url_hook', 'my_function_idk' );`. Inside the function that you want to hooked needed to that:

```php
function get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post = null, $size = 'post-thumbnail' ) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );
    if ( ! $post_thumbnail_id ) {
        return false;
    }
    return  apply_filters('get_the_post_thumbnail_url_hook', $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
}
```

Look at `return  apply_filters('get_the_post_thumbnail_url_hook', $post_thumbnail_id, $size );`

And this function does not have hook. [Look it inside core](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/#source). So you can't "hooked" it.

But you have one option:

Inside [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) we got [wp_get_attachment_image_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) that have [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) And it function have `return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon );`

So you can through the function queue connect to the one at the end of the chain.

Try that:
`add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'my_function_idk', 90, 4 );`. [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, I'll try that, but what that 90 and 4 mean?

Comment: @SenTisso 90 - to run your function later than any other, if someone else will connect to the same hook. 4 this is how many parameters are passed to the hook when it is created, in this case - $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon.

Comment: So it worked pretty well! Thank you! but I have one more question, is it possible to get ID of that image attachment inside that add_filter(), cause I get only that src (which makes sense), but I need ID too

Comment: @SenTisso This created filter passes 4 parameters as I wrote above. Take these parameters in your function like: 
`
function my_function_idk( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ){/*your code*/}
`
"$attachment_id" is what you need. Check it.